# Android put wrong rotation metadata in video files

Tags: android, video, rotation

Why my phone (and one of my friend, but i think then all android phones...) put for a **PORTRAIT** video the rotation metadata to **90**, and for **LANDSCAPES** videos a rotation metadata of **0**?

We are using the default camera app.

Is not the invert? A landscape video is rotated of 90, and a portrait video is rotated of 0! Or I'm wrong?

Thank you in advance.